# Google cloud storage create object denied

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, boto

I have a piece of code in my python application:

```
data = SOME_BYTES
dst_uri = boto.storage_uri(MY_PATH, "gs")
dst_uri.new_key().set_contents_from_string(data)
```

After I deployed to app engine, the code ran into this error.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access denied.</Message><Details>Caller does not have storage.objects.create access to bucket retained-media.</Details></Error>
```

Anyone can help me with that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Caller does not have storage.objects.create access to bucket retained-media." says this is permission issue. You need to grant the robot account for the app permission to write to the bucket that you're using.